General formula for a $f1\to f2$ gamma processes (e.g. $\mu \longrightarrow e\gamma$), understanding the detailed calculation in the paper by Lavoura
I want to work out in detail the paper by Lavoura to get some real practice as a beginning student. I have stumbled upon several problems as I am moving along with the arguments. Firstly, I am not yet sure how to write down or guess the very general form of the amplitude, equation (1).
Next I have trouble working out the self-energy type diagrams where the photon attaches itself with the external fermions. My calculation immediately gives me a divergent answer, and there is no finite part left to be extracted from the self-energy diagrams. However, the paper says that the divergence in the self-energy diagrams will exactly cancel the divergence in the three-point diagrams and there must be some additional finite part from the self-energy type diagrams that will be added to the contribution from the other diagrams. This isn't making sense to me.

The reaction you wrote isn't even possible by the way as QED conserves lepton number. Did you mean $e\to e\gamma$?

@Triatticus Your alternative $e\to e\gamma$ can't conserve energy in the rest frame of the initial electron. The decay in the question, $\mu\to e\gamma$, does preserve lepton number. It doesn't separately conserve lepton flavor, like the more familiar leptonic decay $\mu\to e\nu\bar\nu$. However, flavor is well-known to be non-conserved in the neutrino sector, so there should be some (very small) branching ratio for a decay without the neutrino pair in the final state.

@rob I'm aware of the energy concerns, and I didn't catch in time that I said lepton and not muon/electron number unfortunately much longer after I commented. I'm guessing the reaction is muon $\to$ electroweak blob $\to$ some final state fermions including real radiation.

@Triatticus No I meant what I mentioned. This is possible in BSM scenarios,
